# How to create a nested loop that reads the ints from a file and stores in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

The file looks like this:

> 2 3    (the 2 is the number or rows and the 3 is the number of
>   columns)
>
> 10 2 1
>
> 30 4 3

all the numbers are separated by spaces

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadingFileOfMatrices{

  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
      Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);
      File fileName= new File("m1.txt");
      Scanner inputFile= new Scanner(fileName);

      int row= inputFile.nextInt();
      int column = inputFile.nextInt();

      int [][] array=new int [row][column];

      System.out.println("This array has "+row+" rows and "+column+" columns");
      int firstLine=inputFile.nextInt();
      for (int i=0;i<row; i++){
           int number= inputFile.nextInt();
           for (int j=0; j<column; j++){
               int number1= inputFile.nextInt();
               System.out.println(array[i][j]);
           }
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you read the `row` and `column` from the first row , then the remaining numbers are array elements , using the nested loop , `array[i][j]` refers to the element that is `i`th row and `j`column

```
int row = 0 , column = 0;
  if(inputFile.hasNextInt())
    row= inputFile.nextInt();
  if(inputFile.hasNextInt())
    column = inputFile.nextInt();
  int [][] array=new int [row][column];
  System.out.println("This array has "+row+" rows and "+column+" columns");
  for (int i=0;i<row; i++){
     for (int j=0; j<column; j++){
       if(inputFile.hasNextInt())
           array[i][j] = inputFile.nextInt();
       System.out.println(array[i][j]);
     }
  }
```

Comment: I tried fixing the code but i keep on getting NoSuchElementException

Comment: did you get it with exact the same code i've wrote ?

Comment: yes, i changed what i had different from the one you wrote and i got that.

Comment: for some reason i keep getting errors saying that row and column cannot be resolved to a variable, i tried initializing them at the top in the main but i keep getting the same error